# Create MaterialButtonToggleGroup including MaterialButton(s) with customized style programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components-android, android-togglebutton

I'm trying to create a MaterialButtonToggleGroup with material buttons inside it and I wanna do that with custom styles.

I was able to create that using xml, however, I need to achieve the same result programmatically

here's what I did with xml (I'm using LinearLayout as a root view):

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
  android:id="@+id/group_item_size"
  style="@style/ButtonsToggleGroupStyle"
  >

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:text="Small"
    />

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:text="Large"
    />

  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:text="Family"
    />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

and the code for the styles:

```
      <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="cornerRadius">@dimen/margin_20dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/margin_8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/drawable_button_toggle_group_text_selector</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@drawable/drawable_button_toggle_group_selector</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ButtonsToggleGroupStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/margin_32dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/margin_12dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/margin_32dp</item>
  </style>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a xml layout (`single_button_layout.xml`) to define the single `MaterialButton` with your favorite style:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    .../>
```

Then just use something like:

```
MaterialButtonToggleGroup group = findViewById(R.id.toggle_button_group);

for (....){

  MaterialButton button =
      (MaterialButton)  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_button_layout, group, false);
  button.setText(...);
  group.addView(button);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just put this in .java and nothing in xml

```
  layout=findViewById(R.id.layout);
      
        MaterialButtonToggleGroup grupo = new MaterialButtonToggleGroup(this, null, com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
        MaterialButton btn1= new MaterialButton(this, null, com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
        btn1.setText("Ejemplo 1");

        MaterialButton btn2= new MaterialButton(this, null, com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
        btn2.setText("Ejemplo 2");
        MaterialButton btn3=new MaterialButton(this, null, com.google.android.material.R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
        btn3.setText("Ejemplo 3");
        grupo.addView(btn1);
        grupo.addView(btn2);
        grupo.addView(btn3);
        layout.addView(grupo);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To do it all programmatically you could code the skeleton as follows:

```
MaterialButtonToggleGroup charpathButtongroup = new MaterialButtonToggleGroup(this, null, R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
MaterialButton pathButton[] = new MaterialButton[2];
pathButton[0] = new MaterialButton(this, null, R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
pathButton[1] = new MaterialButton(this, null, R.attr.materialButtonOutlinedStyle);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams charpathgroupParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
charpathButtongroup.setLayoutParams(charpathgroupParams);
game.addView(charpathButtongroup);
charpathButtongroup.addView(pathButton[0]);
charpathButtongroup.addView(pathButton[1]);
```

Be sure to set appropriate params for the MaterialButtonToggleGroup before adding views to it or you will get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
```

Attributes can be added to your LayoutParams and MaterialButtons programmatically as follows:

[image]

I prefer doing everything programmatically for my MMORG game, no layout folder.